# Do I need to escape strings when building a python dictionary with values taken from user-input?

Tags: python

I'm using bottle's request object to get user input

and then i create a dictionary as

```
dict = {...,
        'user_text': request.params.get('user_text'),
        ...,
       }
```

Is there a possible input for which this dictionary could break? Like for example, having the colon character in some way. Should i transform request.params.get('user_text') into unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you are not evaluating user input as Python expressions; request parameters are always Python objects (strings in this case).

Only if you were to interpret request parameters as some form of code (pickles, SQL, python expressions with `eval()` or `exec`) or allow another program to interpret the parameters (HTML in a browser, values interpolated into JavaScript, etc.) do you need to worry about escaping.

Comment: I have to store this dictionary in the database as a JSON encoded string for which I use JSON.dumps(dict). Do I need some escaping for this?

Comment: No, the JSON library takes care of any escaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to escape your `user_text` param. There's no problem, your dict will always be built (if `request.params.get('user_text')` returns something, of course).